# Why in DT package, when escaping=FALSE and hyperkink href target=_blank,the datatable function doesn't work in markdown HTML,but works well in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, hyperlink, dt

I am wondering why in a shiny app the hyperlinks in a `renderDt`(datatable) open well in a new tab, but in a markdown HTML not. In fact, if the hyperlink is the same for multiple rows in the same columns, only the first one is not working (not opened in a new tab). But for the other links (exactly the same), it works.

Do you have any idea how to have a new tab for the first apparition of the hyperlink?

Here is my code in the markdown R chunk:

```
DT::datatable(datatable, escape = FALSE, rownames = FALSE, options = list(
  pageLength=5,fixedHeader = TRUE, fixedHeader.header = TRUE, columnDefs =
                           list(list(className = 'dt-center',
                                     targets = 1:9))), extensions = 'FixedHeader')
```

and the datatable:

```
datatable <- cbind.data.frame(dataset,paste0("<i>",species,"</i>"),  category, substance, duration, exposure, npoint, BAF, report, reference, comments)
colnames(datatable)<-c("dataset","genus","category", "substance", "duration of accumulation", "exposure route", "n (replicate)","Kinetic biaccumulation factor", "report", "reference", "comments")
```

This is in the column "references" where identical hyperlinks can be found. Here is an example for duplicate hyperlinks in my column "reference":

```
> reference
                            
 [2] "<a href='http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.chemosphere.2012.04.052'target='_blank'>Genta-Jouve<i> et al.</i> (2012)</a>"                     
 [3] "<a href='http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.chemosphere.2012.04.052'target='_blank'>Genta-Jouve<i> et al.</i> (2012)</a>"
```

This is exactly the same code for reference[2] and [3], but only the [3] open well in a new tab.

A shiny app that works well for these two exactly same reference in a new tab on the click:

```
 shinyApp(
     ui = fluidPage(DTOutput('tbldatabase')),
     server = function(input, output) {
         output$tbldatabase = renderDT(
            datatable, escape = FALSE, rownames = FALSE, options = list(
                 pageLength=5,fixedHeader = TRUE, fixedHeader.header = TRUE, columnDefs = 
                      list(list(className = 'dt-center', 
                               targets = 1:9))), extensions = 'FixedHeader'
         )}
  )
```

Obtained with Rmakdown HTML, the third link in column reference open in a new tab, the second link doesn't.

[image]